# The meaning of " in the clay for Kim"

Tags: meaning

> I will mention the Spanish leather with which the walls of the dinning
>   room were hung, and the pictures done by Kipling's father **in the
>   clay for *Kim***, which hung all along the dark old pannels of the
>   staircase.

This was  written by Lord Dunsany about Bateman's.

I don't understand the meaning of  "in the clay for Kim"

I am glad if some one would kindly teach me.

Comment: Was Kipling's father alive at the time of writing? Could it mean that his father was buried and so "in the clay?"

Comment: @puppetsock No - the 'pictures' are ceramic bas-reliefs, thus 'done in the clay'.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank so much as usual! It is  a great help for me!

Answer (score 2):

Rudyard Kipling's father, John Lockwood Kipling, was an artist and art teacher, and curator of the museum in Lahore which RK celebrated as the "Wonder House" in his novel *Kim*. In addition to illustrating printed editions of several of his son's works, JLK also created a number of illustrative bas-reliefs in ceramic for RK himself. It is these ceramics that Lord Dunsany refers to.

Here's an example, "On the Road" illustrating *Kim*:

[image: On the Road, John Lockwood Kipling]
source: [Wikiwand](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/John_Lockwood_Kipling)